# How to set color for last row in excel using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas to read data from csv file and write into excel . I have done that one. I want to set bgcolor for last row in excel using pandas. Can anyone plz give some ideas to set color for last row.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `Pandas` has capability to do this. However, once you save your file using `Pandas`, you can reload it and later change the last row color using `xlsxwriter`.

Refer here for how to use [xlsxwriter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39599296/10734525).